# Getting a summary data frame for all the combinations of categories represented in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, aggregate

I am working with a data frame corresponding to the example below:

```
set.seed(1)
dta <- data.frame("CatA" = rep(c("A","B","C"), 4), "CatNum" = rep(1:2,6),
                  "SomeVal" = runif(12))
```

I would like to quickly build a data frame that would have sum values for all the combinations of the categories derived from the `CatA` and `CatNum` as well as for the categories derived from each column separately. On the primitive example above, for the first couple of combinations, this can be achieved with use of simple code:

```
df_sums <- data.frame(
  "Category" = c("Total for A",
                 "Total for A and 1",
                 "Total for A and 2"),
  "Sum" = c(sum(dta$SomeVal[dta$CatA == 'A']),
            sum(dta$SomeVal[dta$CatA == 'A' & dta$CatNum == 1]),
            sum(dta$SomeVal[dta$CatA == 'A' & dta$CatNum == 2]))
)
```

This produces and informative data frame of sums:

```
           Category       Sum
1       Total for A 2.1801780
2 Total for A and 1 1.2101839
3 Total for A and 2 0.9699941
```

This solution would be grossly inefficient when applied to a data frame with multiple categories. I would like to achieve the following:

1. Cycle through all the categories, including categories derived from each column separately as well as from both columns in the same time
2. Achieve some flexibility with respect to how the function is applied, for instance I may want to apply `mean` instead of the `sum`
3. Save the *Total for* string a separate object that I could easily edit when applying other function than `sum`.

---

I was initially thinking of using `dplyr`, on the lines:

```
require(dplyr)
df_sums_experiment <- dta %>%
  group_by(CatA, CatNum) %>%
  summarise(TotVal = sum(SomeVal))
```

But it's not clear to me how I could apply multiple groupings simultaneously. As stated, I'm interested in grouping by each column separately and by the combination of both columns. I would also like to create a string column that would indicate what is combined and in what order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tidyr` to `unite` the columns and `gather` the data. Then use `dplyr` to summarise:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dta %>% unite(measurevar, CatA, CatNum, remove=FALSE) %>%
        gather(key, val, -SomeVal)  %>%
        group_by(val) %>%
        summarise(sum(SomeVal))

     val sum(SomeVal)
   (chr)        (dbl)
1      1    2.8198078
2      2    3.0778622
3      A    2.1801780
4    A_1    1.2101839
5    A_2    0.9699941
6      B    1.4405782
7    B_1    0.4076565
8    B_2    1.0329217
9      C    2.2769138
10   C_1    1.2019674
11   C_2    1.0749464
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over the column combinations, compute the quantities you want and then `rbind` them together:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(dta) # or setDT to convert in place

cols = c('CatA', 'CatNum')

rbindlist(apply(combn(c(cols, ""), length(cols)), 2,
                function(i) dt[, sum(SomeVal), by = c(i[i != ""])]), fill = T)
#    CatA CatNum        V1
# 1:    A      1 1.2101839
# 2:    B      2 1.0329217
# 3:    C      1 1.2019674
# 4:    A      2 0.9699941
# 5:    B      1 0.4076565
# 6:    C      2 1.0749464
# 7:    A     NA 2.1801780
# 8:    B     NA 1.4405782
# 9:    C     NA 2.2769138
#10:   NA      1 2.8198078
#11:   NA      2 3.0778622
```

Answer (score 1):

Split then use apply

```
#result
res <- do.call(rbind,
               lapply(
                 c(split(dta,dta$CatA),
                   split(dta,dta$CatNum),
                   split(dta,dta[,1:2])),
                 function(i)sum(i[,"SomeVal"])))

#prettify the result
res1 <- data.frame(Category=paste0("Total for ",rownames(res)),
                   Sum=res[,1])
res1$Category <- sub("."," and ",res1$Category,fixed=TRUE)
row.names(res1) <- seq_along(row.names(res1))

res1
#             Category       Sum
# 1        Total for A 2.1801780
# 2        Total for B 1.4405782
# 3        Total for C 2.2769138
# 4        Total for 1 2.8198078
# 5        Total for 2 3.0778622
# 6  Total for A and 1 1.2101839
# 7  Total for B and 1 0.4076565
# 8  Total for C and 1 1.2019674
# 9  Total for A and 2 0.9699941
# 10 Total for B and 2 1.0329217
# 11 Total for C and 2 1.0749464
```